# Extend gradle plugin usage for library users

Tags: android, gradle

Using gradle, if we have an android library that declares a dependency as:

```
api("some dependency")
```

apps that use this library also have access to that dependency.

Is it possible to declare `plugins` the same way?
E.g.
In the library:

```
plugins {
    id("my plugin")
}
```

And then have `my plugin` also applied to the app using that library?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @Vencat I did, actually. Unless I'm doing something wrong, it doesn't work.